# Migrate multiselect taxonomy values from node with csv

Tags: 8, nodes, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I want to import companies with csv into Drupal 8 with `migrate_source_csv` module.

CSV:

```
company_name,company_categories,company_size
"Dummy Name","Category 1";"Category 2","2 people"
```

How to accomplish?
Do I need an other plugin: `explode`?

```
    process:
      field_categories:
        plugin: explode
           source: company_categories
           delimiter: ';'
        plugin: entity_generate
        source: company_categories
```

I also found this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2129651#handling_multiple

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.
This is working for me:

```
process:
  title: title
  body: body
  field_company:
    -
      plugin: explode
      source: categories
      limit: 100
      delimiter: ;
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      ignore_case: true
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: company
```

and a CSV like this:

```
id,title,body,categories
6,company,body text,"cat1, some text;cat1, some other text"
```

Comment: This code will also create taxonomy term under categories. Please check if this code is creating the same term twice

Comment: Yes, it is creating a taxonomy term under categories, if it does not exists. I would suggest to add `ignore_case: true` to avoid duplicates?

Comment: yes. you are right